# Parsing json data in Python 2.7 via URL

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, api, parsing

I feel like I'm close, but I can't figure this problem out. All I want is to print the numeric result for the field tpnc. There is only 1 number to print.

Here's my code:

```
import httplib, urllib, base64, json, requests

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
}
barcode = input("Enter a  barcode:")
params = urllib.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'gtin': str(barcode),
    'tpnb': '{string}',
    'tpnc': '{string}',
    'catid': '{string}',
})


#try:
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('dev.tescolabs.com')
conn.request("GET", "/product/?%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
json = json.loads(data)
print json ["products"]['tpnc']
```

Here's the error I'm receiving:

```
  File "bc1.py", line 23, in <module>
    print json ["products"]['tpnc']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

As I see it, products is the key, and then it would be tpnc, but this may be where I'm getting it wrong. Here's the raw Json that is returned (it's the 6th line down).

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "gtin": "05057373842824",
      "tpnb": "059266919",
      "tpnc": "297243995",
      "description": "Tesco Light Mayonnaise 450Ml",
      "brand": "TESCO",
      "qtyContents": {
        "quantity": 450.0,
        "totalQuantity": 450.0,
        "quantityUom": "ml",
        "drainedWeight": "-;-",
        "netContents": "450ml e (PET);650ml e (PET)"
      },
      "productCharacteristics": {
        "isFood": true,
        "isDrink": false,
        "healthScore": 50,
        "isHazardous": false,
        "storageType": "Ambient",
        "isNonLiquidAnalgesic": false,
        "containsLoperamide": false
      },
      "ingredients": [
        "Water",
        "Rapeseed Oil (28%), Sugar, Modified Maize Starch, Spirit Vinegar, Free Range Pasteurised <b>Egg</b> Yolk (4%), Potassium Chloride, Lemon Juice From Concentrate, Salt, Preservative (Sorbic Acid), Stabilisers (Xanthan Gum, Guar Gum), <b>Mustard</b> Seed, Acidity Regulator (Citric Acid), Turmeric Powder, Antioxidant (Rosemary Extract).<BR><BR>"
      ],
      "gda": {
        "gdaRefs": [
          {
            "gdaDescription": "Guideline Amounts Per Serv",
            "headers": [
              "Each tablespoon contains"
            ],
            "footers": [
              "*Reference intake of an average adult (8400 kJ / 2000 kcal)",
              "Typical values per 100ml: Energy 1271.56kJ (307.72kcal)"
            ],
            "values": [
              {
                "name": "Energy",
                "values": [
                  "191kJ",
                  "46kcal"
                ],
                "percent": "2"
              },
              {
                "name": "Fat",
                "values": [
                  "4.4g"
                ],
                "percent": "6",
                "rating": "high"
              },
              {
                "name": "Saturates",
                "values": [
                  "0.4g"
                ],
                "percent": "2",
                "rating": "medium"
              },
              {
                "name": "Sugars",
                "values": [
                  "0.8g"
                ],
                "percent": "1",
                "rating": "medium"
              },
              {
                "name": "Salt",
                "values": [
                  "0.1g"
                ],
                "percent": "2",
                "rating": "medium"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "calcNutrition": {
        "per100Header": "100ml contains",
        "perServingHeader": "Each tablespoon (15ml) contains",
        "calcNutrients": [
          {
            "name": "Energy (kJ)",
            "valuePer100": "1271.56",
            "valuePerServing": "190.73"
          },
          {
            "name": "Energy (kcal)",
            "valuePer100": "307.72",
            "valuePerServing": "46.16"
          },
          {
            "name": "Fat (g)",
            "valuePer100": "29",
            "valuePerServing": "4.35"
          },
          {
            "name": "Saturates (g)",
            "valuePer100": "2.5",
            "valuePerServing": ".38"
          },
          {
            "name": "Carbohydrate (g)",
            "valuePer100": "11.1",
            "valuePerServing": "1.67"
          },
          {
            "name": "Sugars (g)",
            "valuePer100": "5.23",
            "valuePerServing": ".78"
          },
          {
            "name": "Fibre"
          },
          {
            "name": "Protein (g)",
            "valuePer100": ".58",
            "valuePerServing": ".09"
          },
          {
            "name": "Salt (g)",
            "valuePer100": ".97",
            "valuePerServing": ".15"
          }
        ]
      },
      "allergenAdvice": {
        "allergenText": "For allergens, see ingredients in bold."
      },
      "storage": [
        "Store in a cool, dry place. Once opened, keep refrigerated and consume within 28 days."
      ],
      "marketingText": "Made with Free Range Eggs",
      "pkgDimensions": [
        {
          "no": 1,
          "height": 19.3,
          "width": 8.1,
          "depth": 5.5,
          "dimensionUom": "cm",
          "weight": 502.0,
          "weightUom": "g",
          "volume": 859.815,
          "volumeUom": "cc"
        }
      ],
      "productAttributes": [
        {
          "category": [
            {
              "lifestyle": [
                {
                  "lifestyle": {
                    "name": "Lifestyle",
                    "value": "Suitable for Vegetarians"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think requests' response var has a method `response.json` which does the json call against the response contents for you, so you could just write `json = response.json()` Also, pick a name for this variable other than `json`, which at the moment clobbers your import of the `json` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
my_json = json.loads(data) # don't name variable json to evade confusion
my_json['products'][0]['tpnc']
#297243995
```

Comment: Only the first element contains the "tpnc" key so this will raise a KeyError

Comment: @AttilaBognár it's won't in this case but it could generally so it's a good call.

Comment: Thanks so much everyone, I was tearing my hair out!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following might work

```
json["products"][0]['tpnc']
```